# How can I connect to an RDS instance from an on prem network using a site to site VPN connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, vpn

I have a site to site VPN connection from my on prem network to the VPC RDS resides in. I am trying to connect to mysql using the DNS endpoint RDS provides. I am unable to connect to the DNS endpoint but I am able to connect using the private ip that the endpoint resolves to.

I assume that the DNS is internal to AWS and my on prem network can not resolve it.

The RDS instance is publicly accessible.

How could I connect using the DNS endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is right and you need to configure on-premise DNS resolution to internal AWS DNS. I didn't do that before, but [Resolving DNS Queries Between VPCs and Your Network - Amazon Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resolver.html) can help you :-)

Also, you can just open RDS to public internet, but it's not safe (and not your case, I assume)

Comment: Connecting RDS to the public internet is never a good suggestion, even with a disclaimer.

Comment: Yes, but sometimes you have no options

Comment: Its even a recommended scenario by AWS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html#USER_VPC.Scenario4